# Get distance in pixels between 2 LonLat objects in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have 2 OpenLayers.LonLat objects, and I want to determine the distance in pixels for the current zoom between the 2. I'm using OpenLayers.Layer.getViewPortPxFromLonLat() to determine the x and y of the points and then subtract to see the difference between the 2, but the values that I get are very small for points that are 2000km apart.

Here is my code:

```
        var center_lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(geometry.lon, geometry.lat);
        var center_px = layer.getViewPortPxFromLonLat(center_lonlat);

        var radius_m = parseFloat(feature.attributes["radius"]);
        var radius_lonlat = OpenLayers.Util.destinationVincenty(center_lonlat, 0, radius_m);
        var radius_px = layer.getViewPortPxFromLonLat(radius_lonlat);

        var radius = radius_px.y - center_px.y;
```

I'm trying here to draw a circle, giving that I receive a center point and a radius in meters. The LonLat object seems to be ok.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue: destinationVincenty() need and returns coordinates in wgs84 where my map was using spherical mercator projection.

I hope I got correctly the answer, because projections make me dizzy and never really understood them :(. I was looking in the console to the numbers for my coordinates and the coordinates from the map.getExtent() that is used to calculate the getViewPortPxFromLonLat() and I realised they are not in the right order of magnitude, and then it hit me.

So, the code is now:

```
        var spherical_mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
        var wgs84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

        var map = feature.layer.map;
        var geometry = feature.geometry;
        var center_lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(geometry.y, geometry.x);
        var center_px = map.getViewPortPxFromLonLat(center_lonlat);

        var radius_m = parseFloat(feature.attributes["radius"]);
        var radius_lonlat = OpenLayers.Util.destinationVincenty(center_lonlat.clone().transform(spherical_mercator, wgs84), 0, radius_m).transform(wgs84, spherical_mercator);
        var radius_px = map.getViewPortPxFromLonLat(radius_lonlat);

        var radius = Math.abs(radius_px.y - center_px.y);
```

Measured the circles with the OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine, and the size is dead on :D

Comment: I am trying to do almost the same thing, but for a specific zoom level. Do you know how I would go about doing that? Finally my aim is to get height and width in pixel for a openlayer Bounds Object for a specific zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing right. If the distance you get is too small, maybe there is a problem with `OpenLayers.Util.destinationVincenty` function? Have you tried to replace the bearing (0) with anything else - its value seem to be not important in your case. But frankly speaking, I wasn't able to understand how it works while browsing [the source](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Util.js#L970)

Comment: Yeap :). (c)2011 Applied Magic Inc. We made a small paper calculus after which we determined that the LontLat objects are more or less correct, so the last smoking gun seems to be the getViewPortPxFromLonLat()

Comment: `getViewPortPxFromLonLat()` is quite simple - it just takes your zoom level and calculates LonLat based on that - http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Layer.js#L1249
BTW - I always use verbose OpenLayers sources while developing, switching to minimized one only when committing to VCS